# Tkinter obtain the value select from Checkbutton

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to tkinter and i'm trying to get the value select from the checkbutton to my other script but it keep showing me the error below after I choose and click the "Select" button.

Here's my script:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

options =  ["All","Happy","Sad","Angry","Emotional","Disgust","None of above"]

message = Label(root, text ='Select how you feel today: ')
message.pack()

for x in range(len(options)):
    choose = Checkbutton(root, text= options[x]).pack(anchor=W)
        

def selected():
    print(choose.get())
        
result = Button(root, text='Select', width=15, command = selected).pack(pady =6, anchor=SE)
cancel = Button(root, text='Cancel', width=15, command = root.destroy).pack(pady=6,anchor=SE)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

```
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\Python\temp.py", line 22, in selected
    print(choose.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

is there any how i need to change my code so that i can get the value i ticked from my checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need variables for each checkbox. My advice here is to store those variables in a dictionary `all_vars`, so you can access to them easily:

```
from tkinter import * 

root = Tk()

options =  ["All","Happy","Sad","Angry","Emotional","Disgust","None of above"]

message = Label(root, text ='Select how you feel today: ')
message.pack()

all_vars = {}
for opt in options:
    var = IntVar()
    choose = Checkbutton(root, text=opt, variable=var).pack(anchor=W)
    all_vars[opt] = var
        

def selected():
    for opt in options:
        print(opt, all_vars[opt].get())
        
result = Button(root, text='Select', width=15, command = selected).pack(pady =6, anchor=SE)
cancel = Button(root, text='Cancel', width=15, command = root.destroy).pack(pady=6,anchor=SE)

root.mainloop()
```

Output (you get `1` if selected, and `0` if not) :

```
All 0
Happy 0
Sad 0
Angry 0
Emotional 0
Disgust 0
None of above 0
All 0
Happy 0
Sad 0
Angry 1
Emotional 0
Disgust 0
None of above 0
```